How to have no name attached to an email address in GSuite / Gmail / Google Admin?
I'm using a custom domain with gmail for a business account. I've created a user for sales@customdomain.com but this isn't for a specific person and conseqeuently it doesn't make sense to have a name on it. This is the email for a department / team, not a person. But the fields First name and Last name have to be filled in for the user with this email, and then those names are displayed in email threads with this account.
How can I have an email that doesn't have names on it, for cases like this?

Create a new group. A group has an email address, name and description. For details follow the instructions of Create a group in your organization
